# Trouble in installing Basemap in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to install Basemap, and beforehand I already have the prerequisite versions of Matplotlib, Python and Numpy working on my Mac. To install Basemap I am following the instructions in this website http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html

I seemed to progress quite well with the steps, until the very end which is "Check your installation by running from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap at the python prompt." I got "ImportError: cannot import name pyproj" from a line that reads "---> 30 from mpl_toolkits.basemap import pyproj".

Does anyone have any idea? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiled module could be accessible by python. To achieve that you should put the module into python path or you need to add the location of the module to `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

To see the python installations paths you can write these lines to python shell:

```
import sys

for path in sys.path:
    print(path)
```

The code will show the paths python is looking for modules.

After you compile the c library, you need to go to upper folder and run `python setup.py install` as it's said in the installation page. This will put python modules into one of your python paths.

Comment: Thank you scriptmonster. But I am quite new to python and I don't fully understand your instructions. In Terminal I typed your above codes in, and then many paths appears. But may I ask what is my next step? What is a "c library"? sorry..

Comment: The code block is to give information about how python modules works. The module you want to install is uses C library, perhaps written in C. The make (`make; make install`) command compiles it, and put the headers to `GEOS_DIR`. After compiling you need to find setup.py in the packages root directory and run `python setup.py install`.

Comment: Thanks. The setup.py is at location "Desktop/basemap-1.0.7" .So I cd to "Desktop/basemap-1.0.7" in Terminal and then I typed "python setup.py install". Unluckily this time I got "error: unable to open output file 'nad2bin.o': 'Error opening output file 'nad2bin.o''" Btw I followed the instruction in the link and typed "export GEOS_DIR=</usr/local>" if this helps... sorry and would really appreciate your help!

Comment: You should run `export GEOS_DIR=/usr/local/bin`, no `<` or `>` then, retry the process. `/usr/local` is not in your system path. You can check your system path from terminal app by running the command: `echo $PATH` which will give you the output: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem installing basemap-1.0.7.
I found that the file
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/**init**.py
had a reference to axes-grid1, but python lists only module axes_grid.
So I changed grid1 to grid and now basemap imports without error.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on OSX, found after much faffing that Basemap worked fine with a non-native version of python (for me 2.7.12 with everything under /opt/local/Library/Frameworks...) but not with the native version (for me 2.7.10 with most stuff under /System/Library/Frameworks... and Basemap under /Library/...). I did note also that under the native version there was already some mpl_tooklit content and without the permission to add Basemap there you end up with mpl_toolkit contents in multiple places. I wasn't sure if this was the problem specifically but as I said having it all under opt using non-native python was what solved this for me.