# issue installing basemap for matplotlib toolkit multiple versions of geos?

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I try to install matplotlib basemap toolkit for use in ipython but fail...

I followed instructions from matplotlib [site](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html) intallation completes ok but issue as decribed below.

Changed location of GEOS_DIR like in comments of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375965/trouble-in-installing-basemap-in-matplotlib?rq=1) question, again no luck.

I also looked at [this](http://introtopython.org/visualization_earthquakes.html)
installed accordingly from the repos, not sure if I had to uninstall the manually installed version?

No solution yet, seems I already have a newer GEOS dev library installed...? In synaptic i have libgeos-dev 3.4.2 installed... does that conflict?

All installation and compiling from source when in python I get:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    import _geoslib
ImportError: libgeos-3.3.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>>> quit()
```

Seems it cannot find the right file..?

Now out of luck, anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up copying the older version libgeos-3.3.3.so (used by the toolkit) into the folder /usr/local/lib on my linux mint distro...

Answer (score 4):

Ran into this problem with a manual basemap install so it apparently is still a thing. 
My solution was to link libgeos-3.3.3.so into the /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu directory.

```
me@here:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/libgeos-3.3.3.so
```

and poof problem solved. That particular problem anyways.

Comment: Did not worked for me. But this did: `parashar@pd-workstation:lib$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libgeos-3.3.3.so .`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going to the directory where libgeos-3.5.0.so was, and linked libgeos-3.3.3.so to that file.

```
    root@mypc:/# locate libgeos-3.5.0
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgeos-3.5.0.so

    root@mypc:/# cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
    root@mypc:/# ln -s libgeos-3.5.0.so libgeos-3.3.3.so
```

It is not the best solution, but it worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else finds this searching for a similar issue: I compiled basemaps from source and could not load it in python due to missing the same file. I'm not sure what went wrong with the libgeos installation, but I just installed libgeos 3.4.2 from Synaptic (or apt-get, whatever you prefer) and it took care of the problem.

Comment: I'm including it because I came across this thread with the same issue. It turned out that I didn't have any such libraries installed for some reason so I just made the note in case it will help someone in the future. Plus the OP already solved their own problem, so, it doesn't really matter.